# How to free the application from the visual studio debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am having a windows application developed in C# language,Its a simple one form one button application with no logic running in Visual studio 2005 in debug mode.What i want to know is,whether there is a way to free the process from visual studio debug mode and make it run as though launched from exe (double click).This is not any requirement of project this is sheer out of my curiosity.
Just clarifying things
I am very sure about running the exe from the debug /release folder.My question is to free the process after it is launched from visual studio.

Comment: Build a release (or in fact debug) .exe, and simply run it from explorer by double clicking

Comment: Whoever is downvoting - please give an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have attached the debugger, and now want to release it, use the Debug->Detach All command.

Comment: This seems to be the answer ,i will check the option.I tried once but its giving some error

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+F5 or select Start Without Debugging from the Debug menu.

Answer (score -1):

Well... If you want to run your app *without* attaching a Debugger to it, just press Ctrl+F5 from within Visual Studio.

Hope that's what you asked for.